# ScheduledExecutorService as timeout shows no AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, timeout, android-alertdialog, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm trying to implement a timeout behaviour in my app. There should also be a warning (alertdialog) 5 seconds before the timeout actually happens.

I want to use a ScheduledExecutorService to do so.

Here is my relevant Code so far :

```
private final Context context = this;

private ScheduledExecutorService sExService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

private RunnableScheduledFuture<?> sFutureTimeout;
private RunnableScheduledFuture<?> sFutureDisconnect;

private final Runnable timeoutRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        showTimeoutAlertDialog();
    }   
};
private final Runnable disconnectRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        disconnect();   
    }   
};
```

and the methods to handle the timeout behaviour :

```
private void setTimeout(){
    sFutureTimeout = (RunnableScheduledFuture<?>) sExService.schedule(timeoutRunnable, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

setTimeout is called in onCreate(), so the app should disconnect 5s after launch.

```
private void showTimeoutAlertDialog(){

    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Disconnect in 5s")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Abort",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            sFutureDisconnect.cancel(false);
                            setTimeout();
                        }
                    }).show();  

    sFutureDisconnect = (RunnableScheduledFuture<?>) sExService.schedule(disconnectRunnable, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Here's the problems I am facing :

- if the runnable called in "setTimeout" is set to 'disconnectRunnable', it works fine, the app disconnects after 5s.
- when I set it to 'timeoutRunnable', the alertDialog is not shown + the app never disconnects even though 'disconnectRunnable' should be called after 5s in "showTimeoutAlertDialog"!?

I think something with the ScheduledExecutorService went wrong here, but I can't find a solution.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to show AlertDialog not from the UI thread so it will never work The method `showTimeoutAlertDialog()` is called from the worker thread created in the scheduled thread pool. You can use `Handler` for your purpose:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private final Context context = this;

    private static Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable timeoutRunnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showTimeoutAlertDialog();
        }
    };
    private final Runnable disconnectRunnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            disconnect();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTimeout();
    }

    private void disconnect() {
        Log.e("MyActivity", "Disconnected");
    }

    private void setTimeout(){
        mHandler.postDelayed(timeoutRunnable, 5000);
    }

    private void showTimeoutAlertDialog(){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Disconnect in 5s")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Abort",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                mHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectRunnable);
                                setTimeout();
                            }
                        }).show();

        mHandler.postDelayed(disconnectRunnable, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use a Handler before. I wasn't aware of .removeCallbacks(r) method :)

Comment: One more question: What about threads now ? The whole timeout-behaviour is now run on the ui-thread, isn't it ? If yes, is there a workaround for keeping the timeout-feature in a seperate thread?

Comment: You can start a new thread in the ``disconnect()`` method if long running job will be executed here. ``mHandler.postDelayed(...)`` doesn't block UI thread it only places Runnable in the messages queue and delays it for specified time. You can also start a new Thread from this Runnable if you want.